# Null Pointer Exception in Android.

Tags: android

I am very new to Android development and have been following the Big Nerd Ranch book on Android Programming.

I keep getting this error of Null Pointer Exception and I don't understand what the error is referring to.

The app crashes when I press on any thing in the app.

Here is the error.

```
01-17 17:10:54.794      811-811/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onCreateView(CrimeFragment.java:81)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is my code where I am getting the error**

```
    package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

   import android.annotation.TargetApi;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.os.Build;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
   import android.text.Editable;
   import android.text.TextWatcher;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.CheckBox;
   import android.widget.CompoundButton;
   import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;

   import java.text.DateFormat;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.UUID;

   public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";
private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;

private Crime mCrime;
private EditText mTitleField;
private Button mDateButton;
private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
private  DateFormat dateFormat;
private DateFormat timeFormat;
private ImageButton mPhotoButton;


public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID,crimeId);

    CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID crimeId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
    mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public  void updateDate() {
    mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
}


@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
            mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count, int after) {
            // this space intentionally left blank
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
            // this one too
        }

    });
    dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(this.getActivity());
    timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this.getActivity());


    mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);

    updateDate();
    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
            dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
            dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);
        }
    });

    mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
    mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
    mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //set the crime's solved property
            mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
        }
    });

    mPhotoButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_imageButton);
    mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimeCameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //if camera is not available, disable camera functionality
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) && !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        mPhotoButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public  void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
        Date date = (Date)data.getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
        mCrime.setDate(date);
        updateDate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).saveCrimes();
}


 }
```

Any help where I am going wrong would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: NPE on line 81. Guessing either `mTitleField` or `mCrime` is null.

Comment: Check out this line number 81 in CrimeFragment.java

Comment: I think it's mCrime, maybe you're not putting any data, because there's you're initializing(?) of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Date object in Crime class(Crime.java)'s constructor.

```
public Crime(){
mId = UUID.randomUUID();
mDate = new Date();
}
```

You might miss the line

```
mDate = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add try-catch block for exception prone code. Check null with nCrime before using it. Also check why CrimeLab is giving null value.